# LINQ query over non existing fields

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I am trying to query a mongodb collection using LINQ.
My document have the structure below:

```
{ 
    "_id": ObjectId("593fe10f37ce000d844e8972"),
    "MRN": "00038063"
    "Family_Name": "SALAMOUN"
    "First_Name": "SABINE"
    "Maiden_Name": ""
    "Mother_Name": "RANDA"
    "Spouse_Name": ""
    "Address": "Naccache"
}
```

From the C# side, I have created a class that has the below structure:

```
public class cls_Patient{ 
    public string MRN;
    public string Family_Name;
    public string First_Name;
    public string Father_Name; 
    public string Spouse_Name;
    public string Address;
}
```

**Note** that the father_name field is missing from MongoDB document, and created as a field on class level, in order to simulate the data model change (documents within the same collection may have different structure

The querying code:

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://183.183.183.122");
var db = client.GetDatabase("HISEA");
var col2 = db.GetCollection<cls_Patient>("tbl_Patients");

var names = col2.AsQueryable().
  Where(patient => patient.MRN == MFNO &&patient.Father_Name != "")
    .OrderBy(patient => patient.First_Name)
    .ThenBy(patient => patient.Family_Name);
```

the latest instruction queries for the father_name field and  throws the below exception:

> "no matching creator found "

I have tried using the

```
 BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<cls_Patient>(cm =>
  {
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);
  });
```

I have also used

```
MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes.BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
```

On top of the class definition, but both methods did not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that works. Mind you, I wasn't able to reproduce your error message using your supplied code.

The MongoDB query will yield one result assuming you have the exact data in your database that you posted above. This may seem a bit surprising but it makes sense since your sample data does not have a "Father_Name" field. So when you ask for all patients with a "Father_Name" value that is not equal to an empty string (`patient.Father_Name != ""`) MongoDB will find your record because its "Father_Name" value is not present and hence not equal to an empty string.

```
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Conventions;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class cls_Patient
    {
        public string MRN;
        public string Family_Name;
        public string First_Name;
        public string Father_Name;
        public string Spouse_Name;
        public string Address;
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConventionPack p = new ConventionPack();
            p.Add(new IgnoreExtraElementsConvention(true));
            ConventionRegistry.Register("Ignore extra elements", p, _ => true);

            var collection = new MongoClient().GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<cls_Patient>("Person");

            var names = collection.AsQueryable().
              Where(patient => patient.MRN == "00038063" && patient.Father_Name != "")
                .OrderBy(patient => patient.First_Name)
                .ThenBy(patient => patient.Family_Name).ToList();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The proposed solution did not work, however I managed to solve the issue through a turnaround.
IEnumerable<cls_Patient> nameserror = col2.AsQueryable().Where(patient => patient.MRN == "00038063");
 return nameserror.Select(p =>new {First = p.First_Name, Family = p.Family_Name, Father= p.Father_Name }).ToList().ToJson();